# How to randomly empty half of an entire VARCHAR column?

Tags: mysql

I want to reduce the size of a test table by setting half of all the data in a VARCHAR column to an empty string. How can I do it such that the empty string is dispersed randomly throughout the table consisting of 1 million rows?

```
+----+-----------------------------------+
| ID |          VARCHAR COLUMN           |
+----+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | adas                              |
| 2  | //randomly dispersed empty string |
| 3  | sdgsdf                            |
| 4  | sdfs                              |
| 5  | //randomly dispersed empty string |
| 6  | fdhgff                            |
+----+-----------------------------------+
....
```

Note that original data in the column except those set to empty must not be touched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = ''
WHERE RAND() > 0.5
```

Comment: @Jack: and presumably will be faster

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it would be ;-) probably won't be much different with a small test table.

Answer (score 4):

Use a random order and limit the query:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = ''
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT <half-of-your-table>
```